# Output a solid PNG from scratch

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

**Input**: An RGBA hex color `c` (ex. `FFFF00FF`) and an integer > 0 and < 1000 `n` (ex. `200`).

**Output**: Raw bytes of a PNG file such that when the output is saved to a file and opened in an image viewer, an `n` by `n` image filled with the color `c` is displayed.

**Specification**: Your program should output **exactly**:

- a PNG header (`89504E470D0A1A0A` in hex)
- an `IHDR` chunk containing these specifications:

  - width: the previous input `n`
  - height: the previous input `n`
  - bit depth: `8` (`RGBA`)
  - color type: `6` (truecolor with alpha)
  - compression method: `0`
  - filter method: `0`
  - interlace method: `0`
- one or more `IDAT` chunks containing the image data (a solid image of color previously input `c`); may be compressed or uncompressed
- an `IEND` image end chunk

Further details available on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Technical_details), on [the W3 site](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#5DataRep), or via a Google search.

**Restrictions**:

- You may not use any image libraries or functions designed to work with images of any kind.
- Your program must run in under 3 minutes and output a file under 10 MB for all inputs (sanity check).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes will win!

Comment: You say that the file may be entirely uncompressed, but then that it must be under 30kB for all inputs. A `999x999` file has more than 30720 pixels, so that seems self-contradictory.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Hm, for some reason I thought that 30 KB was more than enough. Don't know what I was thinking... edited. (And I only said that you may or may not use compression; whichever you want.)

Comment: Width:              4 bytes
   Height:             4 bytes
   Bit depth:          1 byte
   Color type:         1 byte
   Compression method: 1 byte
   Filter method:      1 byte
   Interlace method:   1 byte

Comment: @technosaurus ... um, what?

Comment: Almost like cheating: http://mainisusuallyafunction.blogspot.se/2012/04/minimal-encoder-for-uncompressed-pngs.html

Comment: Your example isn't correct: bit depth: 8 (RRGGBBAA).  Bit depth 8 is (RGBA) not (RRGGBBAA).

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Ah, thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Perl, 181

```perl
/ /;use String::CRC32;use Compress::Zlib;sub k{$_=pop;pack'Na*N',y///c-4,$_,crc32$_}$_="\x89PNG\r\n\cZ\n".k(IHDR.pack NNCV,$',$',8,6).k(IDAT.compress pack('CH*',0,$`x$')x$').k IEND
```

Size is 180 bytes and option `-p` is needed (+1). Score is then 181.

The arguments are given via STDIN in a line, separated by a space,
the color as hex value (16 chars) and the number of pixels for width/height, e.g.:

```
 echo "FFFF00FF 200" | perl -p solidpng.pl >yellow200.png
```

[image: yellow200.png]

The file size is 832 bytes. The maximal sized image (n=999) with the same color has 6834 bytes (way below 10 MB).

The solution uses two libraries:

- `use Digest::CRC crc32;` for the CRC32 values at the chunk ends.
- `use IO::Compress::Deflate deflate;` to compress the image data.

Both libraries are not related to images.

**Ungolfed:**

```perl
# Perl option "-p" adds the following around the program:
#     LINE:
#     while (<>) {
#         ... # the program goes here
#     } continue {
#         print or die "-p destination: $!\n";

/ /;    # match the separator of the arguments in the input line
        # first argument, color in hex:  $`
        # second argument, width/height: $'                              #'

# load the libraries for the CRC32 fields and the data compression
use String::CRC32;
use Compress::Zlib;

# function that generates a PNG chunk:
#   N (4 bytes, big-endian: data length
#   N:                      chunk type
#   a* (binary data):       data
#   N:                      CRC32 of chunk type and data
sub k {
    $_ = pop; # chunk data including chunk type and
              # excluding length and CRC32 fields
    pack 'Na*N',
        y///c - 4,   # chunk length                                      #/
                     # netto length without length, type, and CRC32 fields
        $_,          # chunk type and data
        crc32($_)    # checksum field
}

$_ =                      # $_ is printed by option "-p".
    "\x89PNG\r\n\cZ\n"    # PNG header
        # IHDR chunk: image header with
        #   width, height,
        #   bit depth (8), color type (6),
        #   compresson method (0), filter method (0), interlace method (0)
    . k('IHDR' . pack NNCV, $', $', 8, 6)
        # IDAT chunk: image data
    . k('IDAT' .
          compress        # compress/deflate data
          pack('CH*',     # scan line with filter byte
              0,          # filter byte: None
              ($` x $')   # pixel data for one scan line                 #'`
          ) x $'          # n lines                                      #'
      )
        # IHDR chunk: image end
    . k('IEND');
```

**Edits**

- `use IO::Compress::Deflate':all';` is replaced by `use Compress::Zlib;`. The latter does export the deflate function `compress` by default. The function
  does not need references as arguments and also returns the
  result directly. That allows to get rid of variable `$o`.

Thanks for Michael's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28134/16143):

- Function `k`: A call of `pack` could be removed by using template `Na*N` for the first `pack` in the function.
- `pack` template `NNCV` with four values optimizes `NNC3n` with six values.

Thanks for VadimR's [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/27086/output-a-solid-png-from-scratch/28133?noredirect=1#comment60720_28133) with lots of tips:

- `use String::CRC32;` is shorter than `use Digest::CRC crc32;`.
- `y///c-4` is shorter than `-4+y///c`.
- The scan line is now constructed by the template `CH*` with the repetition in the value.
- Removal of `$i` by using a value reference.
- Bare words instead of strings for the chunk types.
- Options now read by matching a STDIN input line (option `-p`) with matching
  the space separator `/ /`. Then the first option is in `` $` `` and the second argument goes in `$'`.
- Option `-p` also automatically prints `$_`.
- `"\cZ"` is shorter than `"\x1a"`.

### Better compression

At the cost of code size the image data can be further compressed, if filtering is applied.

- Unfiltered file size for `FFFF0FF` `200`: 832 bytes
- Filter `Sub` (horizontal pixel differences): 560 bytes

  ```perl
  $i = (                            # scan line:
           "\1"                     # filter "Sub"
           . pack('H*',$c)          # first pixel in scan line
           . ("\0" x (4 * $n - 4))  # fill rest of line with zeros
        ) x $n;                     # $n scan lines
  ```
- Filter `Sub` for the first line and `Up` for the remaining lines: 590 bytes

  ```perl
  $i = # first scan line
       "\1"                     # filter "Sub"
       . pack('H*',$c)          # first pixel in scan line
       . ("\0" x (4 * $n - 4))  # fill rest of line with zeros
       # remaining scan lines 
       . (
             "\2"               # filter "Up"  
             . "\0" x (4 * $n)  # fill rest of line with zeros
         ) x ($n - 1);
  ```
- First unfiltered line, then filter `Up`: 586 bytes

  ```
  $i = # first scan line
       pack('H*', ("00" . ($c x $n)))  # scan line with filter byte: none
       # remaining scan lines 
       . (
             "\2"               # filter "Up"
             . "\0" x (4 * $n)  # fill rest of line with zeros
         ) x ($n - 1);
  ```
- Also `Compress::Zlib` can be tuned; the highest compression level can be set by additional option for the compression level in function `compress` at the cost of two bytes:

  ```perl
  compress ..., 9;
  ```

  File size of example `yellow200.png` without filtering decreases from 832 bytes to 472 bytes.
  Applied to the example with `Sub` filter, the file size shrinks from 560 bytes to 445 bytes (`pngcrush -brute` can't compress further).

Comment: Great answer (as always), but golfing can go further - I get 202, + 1 for `-p`. In addition to insights in Michael's answer (`NA*N` and `NNCV` templates), - `String::CRC32` exports by default, `y///c-4` is OK, `CH*` template, `$i` be gone, `\cZ`, barewords are OK, `-p` and `/ /;` places arguments into prematch and postmatch. I wonder if I missed something and score can get below 200 :)

Comment: @VadimR: Many thanks for the useful tips. I could even golf it further by using `use Compress::Zlib;` and got ≈ 10 % below 200.

Answer (score 5):

### PHP 214

I'm not an expert on PHP, there is place for golfing. Tips are welcomed.

```php
<?function c($d){echo pack("Na*N",strlen($d)-4,$d,crc32($d));}echo"\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n";c("IHDR".pack("NNCV",$n=$argv[1],$n,8,6));c("IDATx^".gzdeflate(str_repeat("\0".str_repeat(hex2bin($argv[2]),$n),$n)));c("IEND");
```

Generate a PNG file:

```php
php png.php 20 FFFF00FF > output.png
```

Generate base64 stream (paste the result in your browser address bar)

```php
echo "data:image/png;base64,`php png.php 200 0000FFFF | base64`"
```

Ungolfed version :

```php
<?php 

//function used to create a PNG chunck
function chunck($data) {
  return pack("Na*N", //write a big-endian integer, a string and another integer
    strlen($data)-4,     //size of data minus the 4 char of the type
    $data,               //data
    crc32($data));       //compute CRC of data
}

//png header
echo "\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n"; 

//IHDR chunck
echo chunck("IHDR".pack("NNCV", //2 big-endian integer, a single byte and a little-endian integer
                   $n=$argv[1], $n,
                   8, 6)); //6 also write 3 zeros (little endian integer)

//IDAT chunck
//create a binary string of the raw image, each line begin with 0 (none filter)
$d = str_repeat("\0".str_repeat(hex2bin($argv[2]),$n),$n);
echo chunck("IDATx^".
       gzdeflate($d)); //compress raw data

//IEND chunck
echo chunck("IEND");
```

Comment: It's 214 now, isn't it? And, I can get no correct image from both golfed and un-golfed versions, but I have no PHP experience, so if it works for everyone else, it's me doing it wrong.

Comment: @VadimR, yes 214, you're right. I've checked, the image generated is valid for me.

Comment: For me (I test with PHP 5.4.27.0), image is 4 bytes short - shouldn't adler-32 be appended to deflated data? IE and Chrome are happy to display image as is, FF is not. Different apps behave differently, too, with this image.

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 252 bytes

```python
import struct,sys,zlib as Z
P=struct.pack
A=sys.argv
I=lambda i:P(">I",i)
K=lambda d:I(len(d)-4)+d+I(Z.crc32(d)&(2<<31)-1)
j=int(A[2])
print "\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n"+K("IHDR"+P(">IIBI",j,j,8,6<<24))+K("IDAT"+Z.compress(("\0"+I(int(A[1],16))*j)*j))+K("IEND")
```

This script takes input from argv. Run this script from command line, like `python 27086.py deadbeef 999`