# Using the smallest number of bytes of code, write a program that produces this image

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

## Context:

Gynvael Coldwind, a famous security researcher, published a contest [in his blog post](https://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?lang=pl&id=710) (that is now complete). The goal was similar to the one described here, but with certain restrictions depending on which of the three allowed programming languages was chosen. I found the exercise fun and wanted to extend the challenge to all programming languages allowed.

## Goal:

The goal of this golf is to write a program as short as possible that generates a **PNG** file which, after converting to bitmap shares the same resolution and pixel color values as the following image ([alternate link](https://gynvael.coldwind.pl/img/confidence_2019_golf.png), SHA256: ab18085a27c560ff03d479c3f32b289fb0a8d8ebb58c3f7081c0b9e1895213b6):

[image]

## Rules:

1. The program must work offline, i.e. when the language runtime/interpreter is installed, no internet connectivity is installed to build/run the program,
2. The program may not rely on any external libraries (only use standard library of your language, as opposed to adding libraries from pip/npm/cargo/maven/whatever repositories),
3. The program must complete its operation within 60 seconds on a regular desktop computer (i.e. no brute-forcing the results).

Comment: What do you mean by "external libraries?"

Comment: Is a PNG encoder external? Do we have to output a PNG image, or will a, say, PPM do?

Comment: For me, the link to the original challenge times out. Not sure if that's a temporary problem or a broken link

Comment: @someone a valid PNG. PNG encoder is not external

Comment: @EsolangingFruit I mean restricting oneself to standard library of the used language, as opposed to installing libraries from pip/cargo/npm.

Comment: These always end up being full of long strings being base64decoded. Can you tell us more about the image, to help facilitate other approaches?

Comment: The secondary task of golfing a PNG encoder seems like it might overshadow the main thrust of the challenge.

Comment: @gastropner not that much - if you use zero compression level, there's not that much complexity added.

Comment: @d33tah I believe this still fits the [Cumbersome IO formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/36445) thing from "Things to avoid when writing challenges" extremely well. In particular, a PNG file has CRC checksums that have to be calculated.

Comment: Someone want to do this in Piet?

Comment: @msh210 I think that would require either writing a PNG encoder in Piet (no sane person could ever do that) or hardcoding a optimized version of the image. I think there are some programs for generating Piet programs.

Comment: Do we have a PNG encoder challenge?

Comment: @lirtosiast, I think https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/27086/194 is the only one, and it's rather more restricted.

Comment: Why are external libraries banned again? I thought we allowed them by default as long as it was treated as a separate "language" (e.g. "Ruby + rmagick")

Answer (score 6):

### C#, <s>849</s> <s>793</s> 771 bytes

```c
using System;using System.Drawing;using System.IO;class P{static void Main(){dynamic x,y,i=new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAAA2BAMAAADKYYHhAAAAGFBMVEUAAABdAgSMAwb///+jBAfFgYLRgYOugIE5HrT9AAAA20lEQVR4AWKgHIwCQThAFmVECAsA2qsDk4qBGIzjD7qAn5ngvlvAJJ3AdyscTqAr3PqaQwMgVYATKvQPlED5kQaAng2QBVnoCywBVeFQqKu6im83gcP1GFgVqEMVqiIP25MIzRjlmgSPZNufK/Qj1wC+bSKk2w/gHkDUaFZrEXht+85jcDc6FAHcqgsqvX3fkCxfcFZiaK3xL8EckS0ArfVO8u31C4y+FAQBBgbLAOYE9v8HxgDAgiiPXgk6gPykz8ctOzPIgHl0f8mjB1aDGQuyxeDgx3KB37t6B3NXgUgfIi7ZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"),0,312))),d=new Bitmap(1920,1080),g=Graphics.FromImage(d);for(y=0;y<54;y++)for(x=0;x<96;x++)g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(i.GetPixel(x,y)),new Rectangle(x*20,y*20,20,20));d.Save("s.png");}}
```

Tested with the following code:

```c
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Bitmap a = new Bitmap(@"c:\projects\confidence_2019_golf.png");
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(@"c:\projects\s.png");

        Console.WriteLine(a.Width + ", " + b.Width);
        Console.WriteLine(a.Height + ", " + b.Height);

        for (int y=0; y<a.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x=0; x<a.Width; x++)
            {
                Color ca = a.GetPixel(x, y);
                Color cb = b.GetPixel(x, y);

                if (ca.R != cb.R || ca.G != cb.G || ca.B != cb.B)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x + ", " + y);
                    Console.WriteLine(ca.R + ", " + ca.G + ", " + ca.B);
                    Console.WriteLine(cb.R + ", " + cb.G + ", " + cb.B);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ungolfed:

```c
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        dynamic x = 0;
        dynamic y = 0;
        dynamic b = Convert.FromBase64String("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAAA2BAMAAADKYYHhAAAAGFBMVEUAAABdAgSMAwb///+jBAfFgYLRgYOugIE5HrT9AAAA20lEQVR4AWKgHIwCQThAFmVECAsA2qsDk4qBGIzjD7qAn5ngvlvAJJ3AdyscTqAr3PqaQwMgVYATKvQPlED5kQaAng2QBVnoCywBVeFQqKu6im83gcP1GFgVqEMVqiIP25MIzRjlmgSPZNufK/Qj1wC+bSKk2w/gHkDUaFZrEXht+85jcDc6FAHcqgsqvX3fkCxfcFZiaK3xL8EckS0ArfVO8u31C4y+FAQBBgbLAOYE9v8HxgDAgiiPXgk6gPykz8ctOzPIgHl0f8mjB1aDGQuyxeDgx3KB37t6B3NXgUgfIi7ZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");
        dynamic i = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(b, 0, 312)));
        dynamic d = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
        dynamic g = Graphics.FromImage(d);
        for (y = 0; y < 54; y++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < 96; x++)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(i.GetPixel(x, y)), new Rectangle(x * 20, y * 20, 20, 20));
            }
        }
        d.Save(@"c:\projects\s.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAAA2BAMAAADKYYHhAAAAGFBMVEUAAABdAgSMAwb///+jBAfFgYLRgYOugIE5HrT9AAAA20lEQVR4AWKgHIwCQThAFmVECAsA2qsDk4qBGIzjD7qAn5ngvlvAJJ3AdyscTqAr3PqaQwMgVYATKvQPlED5kQaAng2QBVnoCywBVeFQqKu6im83gcP1GFgVqEMVqiIP25MIzRjlmgSPZNufK/Qj1wC+bSKk2w/gHkDUaFZrEXht+85jcDc6FAHcqgsqvX3fkCxfcFZiaK3xL8EckS0ArfVO8u31C4y+FAQBBgbLAOYE9v8HxgDAgiiPXgk6gPykz8ctOzPIgHl0f8mjB1aDGQuyxeDgx3KB37t6B3NXgUgfIi7ZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC` should work for the image as well; produced with zopflipng, assuming I did everything right.

Comment: Cool! Thanks @someone

Comment: You also most likely do know the length of the array "bytes" in advance; I believe it's 312 or something close.

Comment: You do not have to set y and x to 0 in the `for` loops as they are already 0. Doesn't the Bitmap constructor accept a Stream object directly? You might or might not be able to save bytes by placing the program in the `System.Drawing` namespace (automatically using `System` if my brain works right) and referring to MemoryStream directly.

Comment: Thanks, I'm moving on to a javascript based solution. C# is just too verbose...

Comment: @someone Mind if I use that base64 string? The shortest one that I got was 432 bytes long, `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAAA2CAMAAAAPkWzgAAAAGFBMVEUAAABdAgSMAwajBAeugIHFgYLRgYP///9UI1evAAAA5UlEQVR4Ae2WBYKEQAwERwj9/x9fOpO9dcUhNW6pVSAtSxDkB3yzl7ufE4JC8lNWIghBCABtWVmrPXjNKiElLvjwFwE0WwiXuKZVKQEUcJOmM8/ey92nUytqpSLjlAAX+DuACRQAPwrQBKxaLBS0KrfJwk2afnoHFQx5/g5cACpgVrNR8f4d3MvuD5RL/meqUTYqILe71iWoiijF6PtebgVdJ7JWwUnSwrBwwJ7hc9wjEoJpBZ3io/s4/iWvWSByDnX/EZ176StC8J3p/CWLCHtnzqurFpx5/py0XsEPcUIQgl8Igj+TIw9ZgY4inAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

Comment: @Embodiment I guess that string is not really copyrighted or anything... You should feel free to use it.

Comment: @someone what's the non-slang for zopflipping so I can wikipedia it?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUm Zopfli is a deflate, zlib and gzip compression engine by Google. It compresses better than all other deflate compression things I know as of now, but is (tweakably; as much as you want it to be) very slow (when the file being compressed is not < 1KiB). It (at least for me; I install stuff by typing `sudo apt install stuff` and wondering how does that even work) ships with a tool for optimizing PNG images (as they use deflate as well), `zopflipng`. [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zopfli)

Comment: replace every `dynamic` with `var` will save a few bytes, Also `Bitmap.FromStream` is the same as `Image.FromStream`

Answer (score 4):

### HTML + Javascript, <s>607</s> <s>591</s> 527 bytes

Thank you Epicness and Someone.

HTML, 436 bytes

```
<img id=a src=data:;base64,UklGRgABAABXRUJQVlA4TPMAAAAvX0ANALXIcSTJkST68N2Xs2p6ZJgUYgEpOVBwcYtMwGKJpBDAL5EUqioEEAAFTf8n4Akeel/aoYdx8E3jdbec+Bj0CQIKAqIiKqjd3hEU1L/CRATRBWhApHdtTIzZysYT0r794RjJEja6QbvdpUT9W1xDMYkxMQYEjWM4HPkrhiZRGjZoojYx0THU87bTZpWN2U6bJGMxF1qbRQ69BMYY48POObP4kX5/5753WXNeKm2SAFRBVRKqWK2CKkjmvG1VVbHY7K+aM7lk5mS1qqlaq2raKuh/9u1jI0BVVQNzzmJ3VRVcNluTcPxlBPR/7f3rMRIA><a id=b download>SAVE<canvas id=c width=1920 height=1080
```

Javascript, 91 bytes

```c
b.href=c.toDataURL((d=c.getContext`2d`).drawImage(a,d.imageSmoothingEnabled=0,0,1920,1080))
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wynj3hmL/)

Comment: How are you counting bytes? I count 146 for Javascript and 543 for HTML (the total is correct though). I golfed the Javascript a bit; [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ga7t4xk/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what happened.

Comment: Are you sure you want the "SAVE" link at all? I think you can simply alert `c.toDataUrl()`.

Comment: Yes, I was not sure about that. `alert` does not show all the content, perhaps `console.log`?

Comment: For me, a recent version of Firefox infers the image/png thing by itself, allowing you to omit it (that is, leave `data:;base64,STRING`). I'm not sure about Chrome. Alert clips at `P+77/` for me; is it the same for Chrome, if you're using that?

Comment: Cool, `data:;base64,STRING` also works in Chrome and Edge. Chrome clips the alert at [2000 chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325336/overriding-google-chrome-javascript-alert-box-maximum-string-length-2000). All the duplicate 'A' in the base64 string is bothering me. Replacing AAA with ~ gets it down from 416 to 402 bytes but will need some extra javascript to work...

Comment: Ok that didn't really work [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1dp7e08t/)

Comment: I have no idea how does that work but the quotes around the data URL don't seem to be necessary.

Comment: i already upvoted but... technically... does this create a png file?

Comment: [591 bytes](https://jsfiddle.net/j5mr6gc4/).. I stole some of the ideas from this thread and threw a few bytes off the JS myself.

Comment: @donbright, It generates a PNG file when you click on the 'SAVE' link  ;-)

Comment: @JohanduToit I think the "SAVE" text can be omitted, as the canvas is already part of the link. I was unable to find any further improvements neither to the Javascript nor to the HTML code, so I think we have to either change the approach or the language.

Comment: @someone, just out of interests, how much can you get these [Images](http://files.softwave.co.za/images.zip) compressed? Perhaps using 1bbp with transparency or to a GIF?

Comment: @someone, see my answer below for a different approach.

Comment: @JohanduToit , I was, unsurprisingly, able to reduce the images. Something I'd like to note is that I'm not a black box that shrinks your images in size (I simply feed them to `zopflipng` and similar stuff) and that other image formats can be better for compression. WebP is, AFAIK, supported by Firefox and Chrome, and is better than PNG. FLIF is even better, but supported by, AFAIK, nothing. I was extremely disappointed when the targz archive containing the resulting images didn't fit in a comment, so you can download it at http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=18210440611599235182 .

Comment: @someone, I really appreciate your effort and did not mean to offend.

Comment: Firefox lets me right-click the canvas to save it, but if that doesn't count, why not set the image src instead of the link href?

Comment: Use the base64-encoded webp image `UklGRgABAABXRUJQVlA4TPMAAAAvX0ANALXIcSTJkST68N2Xs2p6ZJgUYgEpOVBwcYtMwGKJpBDAL5EUqioEEAAFTf8n4Akeel/aoYdx8E3jdbec+Bj0CQIKAqIiKqjd3hEU1L/CRATRBWhApHdtTIzZysYT0r794RjJEja6QbvdpUT9W1xDMYkxMQYEjWM4HPkrhiZRGjZoojYx0THU87bTZpWN2U6bJGMxF1qbRQ69BMYY48POObP4kX5/5753WXNeKm2SAFRBVRKqWK2CKkjmvG1VVbHY7K+aM7lk5mS1qqlaq2raKuh/9u1jI0BVVQNzzmJ3VRVcNluTcPxlBPR/7f3rMRIA` instead of the PNG to save a number of bytes I do not want to calculate.

Comment: @someone, Cool, saved 64 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 707 bytes

```cs
#r"System.Drawing"
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;dynamic a=new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAAA2BAMAAADKYYHhAAAAGFBMVEUAAABdAgSMAwb///+jBAfFgYLRgYOugIE5HrT9AAAA20lEQVR4AWKgHIwCQThAFmVECAsA2qsDk4qBGIzjD7qAn5ngvlvAJJ3AdyscTqAr3PqaQwMgVYATKvQPlED5kQaAng2QBVnoCywBVeFQqKu6im83gcP1GFgVqEMVqiIP25MIzRjlmgSPZNufK/Qj1wC+bSKk2w/gHkDUaFZrEXht+85jcDc6FAHcqgsqvX3fkCxfcFZiaK3xL8EckS0ArfVO8u31C4y+FAQBBgbLAOYE9v8HxgDAgiiPXgk6gPykz8ctOzPIgHl0f8mjB1aDGQuyxeDgx3KB37t6B3NXgUgfIi7ZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"))),b=new Bitmap(1920, 1080),c=Graphics.FromImage(b);c.InterpolationMode=(InterpolationMode)5;c.PixelOffsetMode=(PixelOffsetMode)4;c.DrawImage(a,0,0,1920,1080);b.Save("b.png");
```

Only compiles in the interactive window, saves the result in a file called `b.png`

Answer (score 2):

## C (GCC/MinGW), <s>1439</s> <s>1406</s> <s>1386</s> <s>1382</s> <s>1092</s> <s>807</s> <s>806</s> <s>800</s> <s>789</s> <s>787</s> <s>786</s> 777 bytes

-33 -4 -11 -9 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

-6 bytes thanks to [someone](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36445/someone)'s idea

Edit: Why even dynamically calculate CRCs when the output is static? Dropping that part really slimmed things down.

Somewhat beefier than other entries, but such is C life.

Assumes `sizeof(unsigned int) == 4`, i.e. 32-bit integers, and little-endianness.

The earlier RLE scheme is replaced by a slightly more complex one. Most of the image (except the "CONFIDENCE" text) is stored as a series of rectangles. Each rectangle is stored as four characters holding (x1, y1) and (x2 + 1, y2 + 1). We start with the lowest colour in the palette and upon hitting a space character in the image data, we increase the palette index.

I have a feeling further compression could be had by storing colours slightly differently and exploiting the additive nature of the colours of overlapping areas.

The "CONFIDENCE" text is stored as a series of characters holding 6 significant bits, each one of which corresponds to a "pixel" in the text.

```
#define Y*Q++-31
*o,C,x,i,W=5760,H=1080,Z[]={262749,394124,459939,8487086,8552901,8618449,~0};S(b,D,C,B,A,c)char*b;{for(B*=20;B<D*20;B++)for(x=A*20;x<C*20;)bcopy(Z+c,b+B*W+x++*3,3);}(*X)()=fwrite;main(j){char*p=calloc(W,H),d[]="\0\x81\26~\xe9",*Q="&&<57)V;22?E;9LOI3eI[%o7_1yA 7)<;2275;2?EC9I;I3V;I;LI[3_7_1o7_7eA 72<5;9?;_3e7 C;E?G;I?M;O?W;Y?[;]?GAIEMAOEWAYEaAcE??CA?ECG]EaG]9_;]?_ALEMG ?9C;L9M;_9a;_?aAa;c?=A?EIELG I9L;";for(;*Q;)S(p,Y,Y,Y,Y,C+=*Q<33&&Y);for(X("\x89PNG\r\n\32\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\a\x80\0\0\48\b\2\0\0\0g\xb1V\24\0_\5VIDAT\b\35",1,43,o=fopen("a.png","wb"));i<240;i++)"FStuybLGitTTJfRAaTuUzjBGiTVTJrRAFSTtybLG"[i/6]-64>>i%6&1&&S(p,C+1,j+1,C=17+i/48,j=26+i/6%8*6+i%6,6);for(;H--;p+=X(p,1,W,o))*d=!H,X(d,1,6,o);X("*vC\6\xc7\xe3\20W\0\0\0\0IEND\256B`\x82",1,20,o);}
```

Comment: this segfaults on my machine.

Comment: @donbright some compilers/runtimes require `#include<stdio.h>` to avoid segfaulting.

Comment: is stdio considered an external library? if we can include header files like stdio.h then why cant we include header files like Lode Vandevenne's lodepng.h ?

Comment: oh i see, "standard libraries" is acceptable. upvoted!

Comment: Is 16777215 `-1u>>8`? That should save two bytes.

Comment: @someone It is! But it's better than that! Since we're only ever using the lower three bytes of each palette entry, we can forgo shifting and just use `~0`. Thanks!

Comment: Could this benefit from raw string literals (`R"delim([any unescaped bytes])delim"`)? AFAIK they are only in C++, but I think gcc might support them as a extension, or changing this to C++ might even save some bytes anyway.

Comment: @someone It definitely would. You could even just paste raw data into a regular string, and gcc will eat it up. I usually hesitate a bit from doing that, since I don't enjoy using a hex editor for programming. It *would* save loads of bytes, though.

Answer (score 1):

### HTML + javascript, 504 bytes - Not competing

I still need to get the colors sorted out.

HTML, 35 bytes

```
<canvas id=g width=1920 height=1080
```

Javascript, 469 bytes

```
d=g.getContext`2d`
d[f='fillRect'](0,0,1920,1080)
d[a='globalAlpha']=.4
d[l='fillStyle']=`#a00`
'//>7|@2G:|;;5;|DB9>|R<D>|d.<:|h:B8'.split`|`.map(x=>x.split``.map(c=>(c[w='charCodeAt']()-40)*20)).map(x=>d[f](...x))
d[l]='#fff'
d[a]=1
q=(h,x,y,p,z)=>{b=atob(h).split``;for(var n in b){for(j=8;j--;)b[n][w]()&1<<j&&d[f](x+(n%p*8+j)*z,y+((n/p)|0)*z,z,z);}}
q('xkTXucgcKU1RiikFIVVXuiocKWVRiiwFxkTRucgc',520,340,6,20)
d[a]=.4
q('xgADKKEEKKEEBgADISEEISEExgAD',600,520,3,40)
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0jm2af8/)

Comment: I believe you can replace the `...,y+((n/p)|0)*z...` bit with `...,y+~~(n/p)*z`, but I haven't really compared the images for equality. I was not offended by the second last your comment, but just noted that you could perform image compression as well as I could.

Comment: Without the `|0` it calculates a floating point value that blurs the image.

Comment: Doesn't ~~x basically cast to integer? I tried to find a color that matches the rectangles. An alpha value of 0.5 and the color #BA0408 produces extremely close, but wrong results, likely caused by the differences between various image editors. I think that is possible to get around that by tweaking these values slightly. Disclaimer: in case you are not aware of any good utilities for getting exact pixel colors from screen I could suggest `gpick` for Linux or `ColorPix` for Windows.

Comment: I will check that out, thanks. I'm hoping that all the rectangles are using the same color and alpha values.

Comment: See Diff results for [Chrome](http://files.softwave.co.za/cg/ichrome.png) vs [Firefox](http://files.softwave.co.za/cg/ifirefox.png)